# Maintaining the aspect ratio of a scalable image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, transform

I am using the css property transform: translateY to vertically center an image on a page. The width of the image is a percentage of that of the page so that it is scaled if the user enlarges or reduces the browser window.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="..." width="50%">
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
div.item > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This works very well unless the browser window is much shorter than it is wide in which case the height of the image is trimmed or, by setting the maximum height of the image to 100%, is squished. You can see the problem by drastically reducing the height of your browser window while viewing this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0zh4qvLm/. How can I maintain the aspect ratio of the image in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to

```
div.item > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    width:auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

and remove the `width` attribute from your `<img>`

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zh4qvLm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: auto` under your `max-width`. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zh4qvLm/1/)

```
div.item > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```